# How to get Active Directory Groups working with TikiWiki

Tags: active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group, tiki-wiki

So I have seen a number of questions revoloving around this issue, most get stuck authenticating against AD for login on TikiWiki. I have that working without issue.

The problem that I am facing is that there is supposed to be an integration with the Groups in AD so that I can assign privileges and access rights within the Tiki for those groups. Nothing that I have done allows me to pull in the group info, so I cannot segregate them apart without using internal (Tiki only) groups and assigning them after the users log in. In a large company that would be painfully tedious....

Here are screenshots of my LDAP tab and LDAP External Groups tab, sensitive info redacted of course. If I am missing something or have something misconfigured, please help. I followed the walk-through here to set everything up: https://tiki.org/forumthread42893. TikiWiki version is 15.2 (current stable)

**LDAP Settings**
[image: LDAP Settings]

**LDAP External Group Settings**
[image: LDAP External Groups Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured that out. This works for me on Tikiwiki 16.2:

**1. In General Preferences tab:**

- Authentication method section, select Tiki and LDAP
- Uncheck Forgot password
- Uncheck Users can change their password

**2. In LDAP tab, set up as following** (you may need to switch the Advanced mode on to see more settings):

LDAP

- If user does not exist in Tiki: Create the user
- Uncheck Create user if not in LDAP
- Check Use Tiki authentication for Admin login

LDAP Bind settings

- Host: ldap://
- Port: 389
- Write LDAP debug Information in Tiki Logs:
- LDAP Bind Type: Active Directory (username@domain)
- Search scope: Subtree
- LDAP version: 3
- Base DN: DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM

LDAP User

- User DN: OU=All Users (If you want to pull users from a specific OU, if not, leave blank, also remember to omit the Base DN part)
- User attribute: sAMAccountName
- User OC: person
- Realname attribute: displayName
- Country attribute:
- Email attribute: userPrincipalName

LDAP Admin

- Admin user: admin@mydomain.com (in the form of @)
- Admin password:

**3. In LDAP external groups tab, setup as following:**

LDAP external groups

- Uncheck Use an external LDAP server for groups

LDAP Bind settings

- Host: ldap://
- Port: 389
- Check Write LDAP debug Information in Tiki Logs
- Uncheck Use SSL (ldaps) (Because I don't user SSL)
- Uncheck Use TLS  (Because I don't use TLS)
- LDAP Bind Type: Active Directory (username@domain)
- Search scope: Subtree
- LDAP version: 3
- Base DN: DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM

LDAP User

- User DN: OU=All Users (If you want to pull users from a specific OU, if not, leave blank, also remember to omit the Base DN part)
- User attribute: sAMAccountName
- Corresponding user attribute in 1st directory: sAMAccountName
- User OC: person
- **Check Synchronize Tiki groups with a directory** (important)

LDAP Group

- Group DN: (Set Group DN to the specific OU you wish to pull groups from, ifyou wish to use the whole directory, leave blank. Note that as far as I can tell if you specify something here it will only pull from that specific OU, not members of that OU. For example a setting of ou=IT,ou=Authorized Users will pull groups from the Authorized Users\IT organizational unit, but will not pull from the Authorized Users\IT\Admins (ou=Admins,ou=IT,ou=Authorized Users) OU. There may be something to modify this behavior, but I haven't found it. Again, a blank setting will acquire all group information.)
- Group name attribute: sAMAccountName
- Group description attribute: description
- Group OC: group
- Check Synchronize Tiki users with a directory

LDAP Group Member - if group membership can be found in group attributes

- Member attribute: member
- Check Member is DN

LDAP User Group - if group membership can be found in user attributes

- Group attribute: memberOf
- Group attribute in group entry: cn

LDAP Admin

- Admin user: admin@mydomain.com (in the form of @)
- Admin password:

**4. Click Apply and enjoy**

From now on, whenever a user login, all the groups where she belongs will be created on Tikiwiki if they aren't there yet.

I also wrote an article here: http://www.dangtrinh.com/2017/04/ldap-authentication-with-active.html